# Sphere-ring collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, sphere

I'm making 3d basketball throwing simulator and I'm stuck with the sphere-ring collision detection.
It's easy to find the collision normal if we have the collision point with the ring, but I don't know how to detect such collision point since I haven't found a representation of the ring in space.
I've thought of approximating the ring to other shape like octagon then the collision will be with planes, but more processing should be done with this idea.
Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: why not use 8 box colliders arranged like a ring?

Comment: or 8 cylinder colliders...

Comment: So you want a [sphere-circle intersection function](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/75775/39518)? (You can also apply this to the sphere-torus case: just enlarge the sphere by the thickness radius of the torus and shrink the torus to a circle — the collisions are still equivalent)